# Detecting adverse events from EHR's

Tags: events, nlp

I have been given a task to detect the adverse events from EHR (electronic health reports) using nlp. I am very new to nlp and facing few difficulties. I am able to do pos - tagging using cTakes integrated with umls but now stuck at this point.

Can someone tell how to proceed from here? If someone can help me the tagged data set then it would be great.

Please provide me some tips on how to proceed from here.